# Is jQuery runs only client side controll and gives error when we add runat=server

Tags: jquery

I am working on a Portfolio project in which I am displaying Images in a Div "Book" . For giveng it an effect am using a jQuery that set the Div's size to a fixed size(500*700). Everything was going fine.

Now I need to controll the size of the division at runtime(new requirement). as soon as i add runat="server" to div jQuery starts to raise an error "Book is null or not an object" at bold position.

```
Book.appendChild(B_LI);
B_RI = document.createElement("img"); **Book.appendChild(B_RI);**
B_MI = document.createElement("img"); Book.appendChild(B_MI);
```

I am not much familier with jQuery. Is jQuery runs only client side controll and gives error when we add runat=server.

Thanks

Suren

Comment: mark as answer if you fix the problem

Answer (score 2):

When you add runat=server, ASP.NET mangles the ID of the control.

You need to retrieve the ClientID and then refer it as the normal ID in your JQuery code.

Here is the example, where user_options is the object of the HTML control to which you have added runat attribute.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { if (user) { $("#<%= user_options.ClientID %>").hide();});
</script>
```

[jquery and html elements that run at server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921144/jquery-and-html-elements-that-run-at-server)

Comment: I am getting the controllid with getElementById in jquery code already. then where is the actual problem

Comment: What is the ID you are passing. If its not the ClientID , the returned element will be NULL

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is that ASP.NET generates ID s for controls marked as runat=server depending in which container is the control.

Change in JQuery/JavaScript scripts to use `<%= Book.ClientID %>` instead of `'Book'` when accessing to that control.